# Is it possible to make LINQ where filter conditional?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this code, I want to change Where from

`Where(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith(v))`

to

`Where(p => (p.FirstName + p.LastName).Contains(v) if v.length > 1`

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public IActionResult SearchPerson([FromQuery] string v="A", [FromQuery] int page=1)
{
    var personList = _ctx.People.Where(p => p.FirstName.StartsWith(v))
                                .Skip((page - 1) * 30)
                                .Take(30);    
    return Ok(personList);
}
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: you can write any combination of `||` and `&&` - notice: you don’t have to user the lambda syntax you can refactor it to an separate method or local function and call this

Comment: so you may be looking for this: `v.length > 1 ? (p.FirstName + p.LastName).Contains(v) : p.FirstName.StartsWith(v)` here I am using the tenary operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: but it could also be written as `(v.length > 1 && (p.FirstName + p.LastName).Contains(v)) || p.FirstName.StartsWith(v)`

Comment: there are many possibilities

Comment: Rand Random You Solved My Problem, Thank you :::))))

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Where clause, or any number of Where clauses, like this. It is not clear what you want to do if `v` length is not greater than 1, but I hope you get the idea:

```
IEnumerable<Person> personList = ctx.People;

if(v.length > 1) 
{
   personList = personList.Where(p => (p.FirstName + p.LastName).Contains(v));
}
else
{
   //a different Where clause?
}

return Ok(personList.Skip((page - 1) * 30).Take(30));
```

Comment: You may need to declare `var personlist` as `IEnumerable<T>` or you will face compile error on setting the `where` condition

Comment: @RandRandom good call

Comment: @RandRandom I would say `IQueryable<Person>` should be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use && within `Where` clause to combine two conditions

Sample :

```
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "1", LastName = "8" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "1", LastName = "8" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "1", LastName = "8" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "1", LastName = "8" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "1", LastName = "8" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "2", LastName = "8" });

        var test = "1";

        var list1 = people.Where(p => test.Length > 0 && (p.FirstName+ p.LastName).StartsWith(test)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think it will not solve my problem

Comment: did you try it already

Comment: I added .ToList() at the end of query

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```cs
_ctx.People.Where(p =>
{
    if (v.Length > 1)
    {
        return (p.FirstName + p.LastName).Contains(v);
    }

    return true;
})
```

but you can also combine them with && just like @Qwerty said :)